# splitfolders python library only creating folders -no content inside

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create Yoga pose prediction
my dataset folder structure is

dataset:

- class1
  ---img1
  ---img2
- class2

```py
import splitfolders   
input_folders = "/dataset"  
output_folders = "/Spilted_Dataset"   
splitfolders.ratio(input=input_folders, output=output_folders, seed=1337, ratio=(.8, .1,.1), group_prefix=None)
```

But folder that gets created has only sub-folders train, test, valid
there is no images inside

I want folders train , test, valid with images inside w.r.t  specific class